# Azure Python SDK describe Database Postgres Server configuration

Tags: python, azure, sdk

I try to get Data Encryption settings (encryption key and key type etc..) configuration and Security settings (is DB public accessible) of Azure Postgres DB server but I can't find it in the response for servers.get (it's pretty poor response with db engine version, server id, network rule object...) and it does't show IP address range when I describe attached vent rule by virtual_network_rules.list_by_server. I've tried all of methods and properties for PostgreSQLManagementClient but no one showed required information.

How can I get Encryption and Security configuration for Azure Postgres DB Server deployed resource?

```py
from cred_wrapper import CredentialWrapper
from azure.mgmt.rdbms.postgresql import PostgreSQLManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.rdbms.postgresql.models import *

az_subscription_id = os.environ['AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID']

credentials = CredentialWrapper()

postgres_db_client = PostgreSQLManagementClient(credentials, az_subscription_id)

get_vnet_rule = postgres_db_client.virtual_network_rules.list_by_server(server_name=serv_name, resource_group_name=rg_name)

get_db = postgres_db_client.servers.get(server_name=serv_name, resource_group_name=rg_name)

print(get_db)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per [azure-sdk-for-python/test_cli_mgmt_postgresql.py at c8291ac6cb0dbd865da03a88dd2bcb9279e2c4a6 · Azure/azure-sdk-for-python · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/c8291ac6cb0dbd865da03a88dd2bcb9279e2c4a6/sdk/rdbms/azure-mgmt-rdbms/tests/test_cli_mgmt_postgresql.py), you can try following security configuration:

```
# Update a server's threat detection policy with all parameters[put]
# BODY = {
#  "properties": {
#  "state": "Enabled",
#  "email_account_admins": True,
#  "email_addresses": [
#  "testSecurityAlert@microsoft.com"
#  ],
#  "disabled_alerts": [
#  "Access_Anomaly",
#  "Usage_Anomaly"
#  ],
#  "retention_days": "5",
#  "storage_account_access_key": "sdlfkjabc+sdlfkjsdlkfsjdfLDKFTERLKFDFKLjsdfksjdflsdkfD2342309432849328476458/3RSD==",
#  "storage_endpoint": "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net"
#  }
# }
# result = self.mgmt_client.server_security_alert_policies.create_or_update(resource_group.name, SERVER_NAME, BODY)
# result = result.result()
# Update a server's threat detection policy with minimal parameters[put]
# BODY = {
#  "properties": {
#  "state": "Disabled",
#  "email_account_admins": True
#  }
# }
# result = self.mgmt_client.server_security_alert_policies.create_or_update(resource_group.name, SERVER_NAME, BODY)
# result = result.result()

# # Get a server's threat detection policy[get]
# result = self.mgmt_client.server_security_alert_policies.get(resource_group.name, SERVER_NAME)
```

For encryption, I didn’t find any documentation/code, you can open an issue on GitHub: [Issues · Azure/azure-sdk-for-python · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues)

Comment: Thank you ,  but unfortunately it didn't help me , it doesn't show required parameters, I've tried all methods for PostgreSQLManagementClient and no success.